# microsoft excel, multiple formulas in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like some help on putting multiple formulas in one cell.

if I enter 1 in g11 I would like it to use the below formula
=if(H11="","",I11/(230*H11))

if I enter 3 in g11 I would like it to use the below formula
=if(H11="","",I11/(sqrt(3)*400*H11*(E11/100)))

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if any other number is entered in G11?

Comment: Apparently this was a drive-by user: unregistered, posted the question and vanished.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same IF function to test G11 cell as well: 
(use this formula in single line)

```
=if(G11=1,  
    if(H11="","",I11/(230*H11)), 
    if(G11=3, 
            if(H11="","",I11/(sqrt(3)*400*H11*(E11/100))),
            ""
      )
   )
```

`=if(G11=1,` to test if its value is 1
        `if(H11="","",I11/(230*H11)),` True condition run your formula for 1
        `if(G11=3,` If it was False, test its value for 3
              `if(H11="","",I11/(sqrt(3)*400*H11*(E11/100))),` if G11 is 3 then run your second formula
              `""` if G11 something else do nothing
      `)` close if(G11=3,,)
`)` close if (G11=1,,)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 =IF(G11=1,IF(H11="","",I11/(230*H11)),IF( G11=3,IF(H11="","",I11/(SQRT(3)*400*H11*(E11/100))),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you’ve noticed that your two (optional) formulas are *very* similar:

```
=if(H11="","",I11/(230        *H11          ))
 ↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕↕           ↕↕↕↕          ↕↕
=if(H11="","",I11/(sqrt(3)*400*H11*(E11/100)))
```

and you can rearrange the second formula to simplify it
and increase the similarity:

```
 400*H11*(E11/100)
=400*(E11/100)*H11
=(400*E11/100)*H11
=(E11*400/100)*H11
=E11*(400/100)*H11
=E11 *   4   * H11
=4*E11*H11
```

So your second formula reduces to

```
=if(H11="","",I11/(sqrt(3)*4*E11*H11))
```

We can take advantage of that similarity to simplify the overall formula
(which has been given in a couple of other answers) to

```
=if(H11="","",I11/(IF(G11=1,230,IF(G11=3,sqrt(3)*4*E11,0))*H11))
```

Note that, if `G11` is anything other than 1 or 3,
this explicitly does a division by 0, which will cause an error. 
Don’t use this answer if that is an issue for you.